# Randomly create a Geopoint within 50 feet of a given Geopoint (Spatial SQL)

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, geography

I would like to create a random GeoPoint within 50 feet of a given GeoPoint. (Using SQL Server 2008 or IPhone SDK)

Can I just add some number to the long & lat to create this random Geopoint?

Example:

```
mylatdistance = Random(1,50) newlat = lat + mylatdistance
```

or

Is this a Spatial SQL/area problem?

Thanks

Comment: What distribution do you want? Uniformly placed anywhere in a 50 foot radius circle?

Comment: Just a thought; on the iphone can you use the reciprocal of the get  distance between two points functionality to get a location X distance away?

Comment: Mark-Any single point within +-50 foot Radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach should work, as long as you scale the delta_longitude values by a factor of 1/cos(latitude), since 1 degree of latitude only equals 1 degree of longitude at the equator.  If you don't do this scaling, your random ensemble of points will get more "squashed" in the longitude dimension as your center point moves away from the equator.

Comment: I See. Thanks Jim. So I can treat this as a more simple Math problem - if I scale the longitude to compensate for curvature. Gr8 Advice. Thx